# Sequelize addConstraint syntax

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Im trying to add two tables, Playlist and Label.
Label optionally has a playlist, many playlists can relate to the same label.

In order to add the foreign key constraint to playlist im trying to add it using addConstraint.
The docs are terrible on this .

This is what i have:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Playlist", {
      id: { type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
      track_uri: Sequelize.STRING,
      track: Sequelize.STRING(150),
      artist: Sequelize.STRING(150),
      added_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: new Date(),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: new Date(),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      is_album_track: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      label: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
    });

    await queryInterface.createTable("Label", {
      id: { type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true },
      playlist_link: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(150),
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
      email: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
      playlist: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        foreignKey: true,
        references: {
          model: "Playlist",
          label: "id",
        },
      },
    });

    await queryInterface.addConstraint("Playlist", {
      type: "foreign key",
      fields: ["label"],
      name: "label_fkey",
      references: {
        table: "Label",
        field: "id",
      },
      onDelete: "cascade",
      onUpdate: "cascade",
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Label");
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Playlist");
  },
};
```

Im getting this error:

`ERROR: column "label" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`

Comment: I know it's been a while, but is it possible that the error might have been caused by models in the `models` directory of the project?  I was able to run the `up` script without any errors.  The `down` script produced the error `cannot drop table "Label" because other objects depend on it`, but that can be fixed by adding a statement to the `down` script to remove the constraint...  After that, both the `up` and the `down` scripts run without any errors, at least when using `postgres`.